# Why is my function not being recognized?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning about modular javascript. I don't know why my the functions that I made in a object aren't being recognized. This is for a list of people application. Can someone take a look at it? 
This is my people.js file

```
(() => {
    var people = {
        people: ['Will', 'Laura'],
        init: () => {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.render();
        },
        cacheDom: () => {
            this.$el = $('#peopleModule');
            this.$button = this.$el.find('button');
            this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
            this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
            this.template = this.$el.find('#people-template').html();
        },
        bindEvents: ()=>{
            this.$button.on('click', this.addPerson.bind(this));
        },
        render: () =>{
            var data = {
                people: this.people,
            };
            this.$ul.html(Mustache.render(this.template,data));
        },
        addPerson: () => {
            this.people.push(this.input.val());
            this.render();
        }
    };

    people.init();
})();
```

And here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Nate</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>This is my Wonderful application</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="peopleModule">
        <h1>People</h1>
        <input placeholder="name" type="text">
        <button id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
        <ul id="people">
            <script id="people-template" type="text/template">
                    {{#people}}
                        <li>
                            <span>{{.}}</span>
                            <i class="del">X</i>
                        </li>
                    {{/people}}
                </script>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.1.2/mustache.min.js"></script>
    <script src="people.js" type="text/template"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It would be much appreciated. Javascript is just so overwhelming!

Comment: What sort of error are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

That's because arrow functions are automatically bound to the outside `this`, which is `window` in your case. The `this` inside of your functions isn't what you think it is (try `console.log(this)` in any of your functions, to see what I'm referring to)

Instead, use the full version: `init: function() {` or the short method version: `init() {`

Comment: What do you mean by that? So if I were to use arrow functions in es6, I would not have to use the keyword this when declaring and calling methods/properties?

Comment: Yes, Nate.

See: https://rainsoft.io/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

The main purpose of arrow functions are the lexical this.

Answer (score 0):

`text/template` is not going to get run by the browser. Even if `people.js` is a JavaScript file, your browser won't run it because it doesn't know what to do with `text/template`.

```
<script src="people.js"></script>
```

Remove `type` attribute.